# Where should input validation go when using Dart with Redux (package:redux)?

Tags: dart, redux

I'm using Dart with [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux), and I need to perform synchronous input validation on a login form. Where should my validation logic go?

This topic has been discussed a lot in the JavaScript world, for example in the [Redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1165).
However:

- Action creators aren't a common pattern in Redux with Dart
- There are many subtle differences between Redux with Dart and Redux with JavaScript

Is there a "right" way to perform input validation with Dart?

There are a few ways I've come up with:

1. In the action constructor

```dart
class CredentialsUpdatedAction {
  final String? email;
  final String? password;
  final CredentialValidationResult emailValidationResult;
  final CredentialValidationResult passwordValidationResult;

  CredentialsUpdatedAction({this.email, this.password})
      : emailValidationResult = validateEmail(email),
        passwordValidationResult = validatePassword(password);
}
```

2. With middleware

```dart
class CredentialsUpdatedAction {
  final String? email;
  final String? password;

  const CredentialsUpdatedAction({this.email, this.password});
}

class CredentialsValidatedAction {
  final CredentialValidationResult emailValidationResult;
  final CredentialValidationResult passwordValidationResult;

  const CredentialsValidatedAction({
    required this.emailValidationResult,
    required this.passwordValidationResult,
  });
}

AppState credentialValidationMiddleware(
  Store<AppState> store,
  CredentialsUpdatedAction action,
  NextDispatcher next,
) {
  next(action);
  store.dispatch(
    CredentialsValidatedAction(
      emailValidationResult: validateEmail(action.email),
      passwordValidationResult: validatePassword(action.password),
    ),
  );
}
```

3. In the reducer

```dart
AppState credentialsUpdatedReducer(AppState state, CredentialsUpdatedAction action) {
  return state.copyWith(
    email: action.email,
    password: action.password,
    emailValidationResult: validateEmail(action.email),
    passwordValidationResult: validatePassword(action.password),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the answer doesn't really change between JS and Dart here:

1. Action creators/constructors don't have access to full up-to-date state. Not a good option.
2. Middleware like you showed it would require another dispatched action, which at least in React would require another rerender. I'll just assume the same fort Dart.
3. Reducers are the way to go. You should have as much business logic as you can in here anyways, to keep it in one place.

Generally, for React we recommend to [avoid putting form state in redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux). Reasoning might be different for Dart, might not. Give it a read.